# MINUS operator in MySQL query

Tags: mysql

I'm trying to figure out the set difference from user table [URLs visited by user1 not by user2].

```
(select u1.url from user u1 where u1.userid='user1') minus (select u2.url from user u2 where u2.userid='user2');
```

But this query doesn't work in mysql. Can anyone help me on this.

Comment: yes. These User tables are same.

Comment: you mean `desc user` ?. BTW why that is important?

Comment: userid - bigint(20) and url - varchar(255)

Comment: names are userid and url respectively

Comment: I have edited your example I added what I need, make an example like this of your table and the result what you want

Comment: @FerhadOthman I rejected your edit, this question is a duplicate and already has an answer, so it is doomed to be closed and does not need solving